# Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I see the following errors when trying to start my app...

```
> css-modules@1.0.0 start /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules
```

> webpack && open index.html

```
(node:5706) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:802
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:802:9)
    at /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1203:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:547:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at _addModuleChain (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1054:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/Users/johnnynolan/Repos/css-modules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:980:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! css-modules@1.0.0 start: `webpack && open index.html`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the css-modules@1.0.0 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/johnnynolan/.npm/_logs/2018-07-17T14_04_42_021Z-debug.log
```

Comment: css-modules might be throwing something. Post the whole stack trace and your webpack config

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to something more along the lines of "How can I resolve this?" instead of "Has anyone seen this before?"

Comment: extract-text-plugin does not work with Webpack v4

Answer (score 198):

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@next
```

This did the trick for me!

Comment: The @next brought me the "^4.0.0-beta.0", precisely what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 86):

Most of the comments here https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/701
 point to `extract-text-plugin` change it to `mini-css-extract-plugin` instead.

From the Github repo of `extract-text-webpack-plugin`  https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin

> ⚠️ Since webpack v4 the extract-text-webpack-plugin should not be used
>   for css. Use mini-css-extract-plugin instead.

Head over to 
`mini-css-extract-plugin` on how to swap/upgrade it
 https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin

Answer (score 26):

Yea, I got the same issue with webpack `4.10.2`. The problem is fixed after I swap the `extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin` to `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

Here's the webpack config changes:

```
-const ExtractCssChunks = require('extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin')
+const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  name: 'client',
  target: 'web',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
-       use: ExtractCssChunks.extract({
-         use: 'css-loader'
-       })
+       use: [
+         {
+           loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
+         },
+         "css-loader"
+       ]
      }
    ]
  },
// 
// other config........
//
   plugins: [
-    new ExtractCssChunks(),
+    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
+        filename: `components/[name].css`
+    }),
     //
     // other config........
     //
   ]
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: It helped more than the above answers indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I had fixed the bug by using the version `4.0.0-beta.0` of `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: Updating to 4.0.0-beta.0 also fixed my issue

Comment: VS Code didnt have an auto complete for 4.x so thanks for saving me another google search with an explicit version.

Comment: what path is that?