# Unable to run `npm run prod` on production server . Chunk.entrypoints error is coming

Tags: reactjs, webpack, laravel-mix

`npm run prod` command is not running on production server. 
My configurations are :

`node version v10.9.0
npm version 6.2.0`

Here's the error

`Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:849:9)
    at /home/ubuntu/warehouse/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /home/ubuntu/warehouse/node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1244:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:624:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at _addModuleChain (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1095:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1007:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)`

Here's the code of `package.json`

`{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.11",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app",
        "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "antd": "^3.10.2",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
        "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "qs": "^6.5.2",
        "query-string": "^6.2.0",
        "rc-table": "^6.4.2",
        "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
        "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
        "react-scripts": "^2.0.5",
        "redux": "^4.0.1",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "styled-components": "^4.0.2"
    }
}`

And here's the webpack
[image]

And the error message
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383618/chunk-entrypoints-use-chunks-groupsiterable-and-filter-by-instanceof-entrypoint)

Comment: did not help me